# D struct copy constructor

Tags: constructor, d, copy-constructor

Is it possible to call struct copy constructor explicitly, like in C++? Can I write something like this:

```d
struct foo {
    void bar() {}
}

foo f;
foo(f).bar();
```

Or I always need to assign new value to some varialbe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, technically, D doesn't even have copy constructors. Rather, structs can have postblit constructors. e.g.

```d
struct S
{
    this(this)
    {
    }
}
```

In general, D tries to move structs as much as possible and not copy them. And when it does copy them, it does a bitwise copy of the struct and then runs the postblit constructor (if there is one) to mutate the struct after the fact to do stuff that needs to be done beyond a bitwise copy - e.g. if you want a deep copy of a member

```d
struct S
{
    this(this)
    {
        if(i !is null)
            i = new int(*i);
    }

    int* i;
}
```

A copy constructor (in C++), on the other hand, constructs a new struct/class and initializes each member with a copy of the corresponding member in the struct/class being copied - or with whatever it's initialized with in the copy constructor's initializer list. It doesn't copy and then mutate like happens with D's postblit constructor. So, a copy constructor and a postblit constructor are subtly different.

One of the side effects of this is that while all structs/class in C++ have copy constructors (the compiler always generates one for you if you don't declare one), not all structs in D have postblit constructors. In fact, most don't. The compiler will generate one if the struct contains another struct that has a postblit constructor, but otherwise, it's not going to generate one, and copying is just going to do a bitwise copy. And, if there is no postblit construct, you can't call it implicitly or explicitly.

Now, if we compile this

```d
struct A
{
}
pragma(msg, "A: " ~ __traits(allMembers, A).stringof);
```

it prints

```
A: tuple()
```

`A` has no members - be it member variables or functions. None have been declared, and the compiler has generated none.

```d
struct B
{
    A a;
    string s;
}
pragma(msg, "B: " ~ __traits(allMembers, B).stringof);
```

prints

```
B: tuple("a", "s")
```

It has two members - the explicitly declared member variables. It doesn't have any functions either. Declaring member variables is not a reason for the compiler to generate any functions. However, when we compile

```d
struct C
{
    this(this)
    {
        import std.stdio;
        writeln("C's postblit");
    }

    int i;
    string s;
}
pragma(msg, "C: " ~ __traits(allMembers, C).stringof);
```

it prints

```
C: tuple("__postblit", "i", "s", "__xpostblit", "opAssign")
```

Not only are its two member variables listed, but it also has `__postblit` (which is the explicitly declared postblit constructor) as well as `__xpostblit` and `opAssign`. `__xpostblit` is the postblit constructor generated by the compiler (more on that in a second), and `opAssign` is the assignment operator which the compiler generated (which is needed, because `C` has a postblit constructor).

```d
struct D
{
    C[5] sa;
}
pragma(msg, "D: " ~ __traits(allMembers, D).stringof);
```

prints

```
D: tuple("sa", "__xpostblit", "opAssign")
```

Note that it has `__xpostblit` but not `__postblit`. That's because it does not have an explitly declared postblit constructor. `__xpostblit` was generated to call the postblit constructor of each of the member variables. `sa` is a static array of `C`'s, and `C` has a postblit constructor. So, in order to copy `sa` properly, the postblit constructor for `C` must be called on each of the elements in `sa`. `D`'s `__xpostblit` does that. `C` also has `__xpostblit`, but it doesn't have any members with postblit constructors, so its `__xposblit` just calls its `__postblit`.

```d
struct E
{
    this(this)
    {
        import std.stdio;
        writeln("E's postblit");
    }

    C c;
}
pragma(msg, "E: " ~ __traits(allMembers, E).stringof);
```

prints

```
E: tuple("__postblit", "c", "__xpostblit", "opAssign")
```

So, `E` - like `C` - has both `__postblit` and `__xpostblit`. `__postblit` is the explicit postblit constructor, and `__xpostblit` is the one generated by the compiler, However, in this case, the struct actually has member variables with a postblit constructor, so `__xpostblit` has more to do than just call `__postblit`.

If you had

```d
void main()
{
    import std.stdio;
    C c;
    writeln("__posblit:");
    c.__postblit();
    writeln("__xposblit:");
    c.__xpostblit();
}
```

it would print

```
__posblit:
C's postblit
__xposblit:
C's postblit
```

So, there's no real difference between the two, whereas if you had

```d
void main()
{
    import std.stdio;
    D d;
    writeln("__xposblit:");
    d.__xpostblit();
}
```

it would print

```
__xposblit:
C's postblit
C's postblit
C's postblit
C's postblit
C's postblit
```

Notice that `C`' postblit gets called 5 times - once for each element in `D`'s member, `sa`. And we couldn't call `__postblit` on `D`, because it doesn't have an explicit postblit constructor -
just the implicit one.

```d
void main()
{
    import std.stdio;
    E e;
    writeln("__posblit:");
    e.__postblit();
    writeln("__xposblit:");
    e.__xpostblit();
}
```

would print

```
__posblit:
E's postblit
__xposblit:
C's postblit
E's postblit
```

And in this case, we can see that `__postblit` and `__xpostblit` are different. Calling `__postblit` just calls the explicitly declared postblit constructor, whereas `__xpostblit` calls it and the postblit constructors of the member variables.

And of course, since, `A` and `B` don't have posblit constructors and no members that have them, it would be illegal to call either `__postblit` or `__xpostblit` on them.

So, yes, you can call the postblit constructor explicitly - but only if it has one, and you almost certainly shouldn't be calling it. If a function starts with `__`, or it's one of the overloaded operators (and thus starts with `op`), then it almost never should be called explicitly - and that includes the postblit constructor. But if you do find a legitimate reason to call it, remember that you're probably going to want to call `__xpostblit` rather than `__postblit`, otherwise the postblit for the member variables won't be run. You can test for it by doing `__traits(hasMember, S1, "__xpostblit")` or by using the badly named [`hasElaborateCopyConstructor`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits#hasElaborateCopyConstructor) from std.traits (most code should use `hasElaborateCopyConstructor`, since it's more idiomatic). If you want to call `__postblit` for some reason, you'll need to test for it with `__traits` rather than std.traits though, because pretty much nothing outside of druntime cares whether a type declared `__postblit`. The stuff that does care about posblit constructors cares about `__xpostblit`, since that can exist whether `__postblit` was declared or not.

Answer (score 2):

D doesn't have copy constructors per se, but you could call the implicit constructor with the contents of the existing one (which would create a shallow copy at least) with

```d
foo(f.tupleof).bar()
```

The `f.tupleof` gives the list of struct members in a form that is suitable for automatic expansion to a function argument list.